# how can i stretch collectionView height in tableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, collectionview

i want to stretch collectionView height in tableView.

as the gitHub App's Label (below picture),
when the collectionViewCell's width excess collectionView's width,
I want to set collectionViewCell in a new line

To set cell in the new line, i tried to use flowlayout.
but it did not be increased height. just can scroll in collectionView. .
unfortunately, tableView's height did not be increased

what's the best way to do this ?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This approach from [SRP-Achiever](https://stackoverflow.com/users/527704/srp-achiever) should work.

```
override func systemLayoutSizeFitting(_ targetSize: CGSize, withHorizontalFittingPriority horizontalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority, verticalFittingPriority: UILayoutPriority) -> CGSize {
        collectionView.layoutIfNeeded()
        collectionView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: targetSize.width , height: 1)
        return collectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
}
```